# Character Encoding during REST GET API Call

Tags: java, json, rest, character-encoding

I have a json data

```
{

  "description": "Architectures of Adobe\ufffds AEM Forms and LiveCycle ES4 systems. IT architects who are considering Adobe\ufffds AEM Forms and LiveCycle ES4 so\ufffdftware for their enterprise\ufffds form and document systems.",

  "title" : "This course includes an introduction to the Creative Cloud and services such as Libraries, Adobe Stock, Typekit, Mobile Apps, and Bēhance."
}
```

Java code to get this data is-

```
    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
    HttpMethod method = new GetMethod(url);
    method.addRequestHeader("accept", "application/json");
    method.addRequestHeader("X-API-Key", apiKey);
    method.addRequestHeader("certificate", certificate);
    int status = httpClient.executeMethod(method);
    JSONObject data = (JSONObject) JSONValue.parse(method.getResponseBodyAsString());
    String desc = data.get("description").toString();
    String data = data.get("title").toString();
```

However I get the results as-

desc - Architectures of Adobeï¿½s AEM Forms and LiveCycle ES4 systems. IT architects who are considering Adobeï¿½s AEM Forms and LiveCycle ES4 soï¿½ftware for their enterpriseï¿½s form and document systems.

data -  This course includes an introduction to the Creative Cloud and services such as Libraries, Adobe Stock, Typekit, Mobile Apps, and BÄhance

Seems to be an encoding issue..Any idea how to fix this....Thanks

Comment: Why does your text have the `\ufffd` (�) replacement character in it in the first place? Seems like you had character set conversion issues before you even got to this point.

Comment: The Json data is coming in this format from the 3rd party API....I guess i need to do the proper encoding for this....but dont know how..........The intended output for desc has to be - Architectures of Adobe's AEM Forms and LiveCycle ES4 systems. IT architects who are considering Adobe's AEM Forms and LiveCycle ES4 software for their enterprise's form and document systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to include Accept-Charset in the request header... Hopefully the server honors this and sends the appropriate charset as a part of Content-Type response header.. this [RFC 2616](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt) states that Accept-Charset should be honored by the server

Possible values for Accept-Charset include but are not limited to...

utf-8

iso-8859-1

refer - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Charset

Comment: This header [seems to be discouraged now](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Charset).